# data filter by date in R

Tags: r, filter

I have data like this:

```
Date             Expiry          Close
2009-05-01       2009-06-26       12
2009-05-01       2009-05-26       22
2009-05-01       2010-05-23       36
2009-05-01       2009-07-26       32
2009-12-01       2009-12-26       33
2009-12-01       2010-01-24       36
2009-12-01       2010-02-26       32
```

Now I want to filter data(row wise) for those dates whose *Expiry* lies in the same month of *Date* or *Expiry* lie in the next immediate month of *Date*. If *Expiry* lie beyond next immediate month of *Date*, I want to exclude them.

So here I want desired data:

```
2009-05-01       2009-06-26       12    #Next immediate month  
2009-05-01       2009-05-26       22    #Same Month
2009-12-01       2009-12-26       33    #Same Month
2009-12-01       2010-01-24       36    #Next immediate month
```

I have both Date and Expiry in POSIXlt format.
Please help. I have such 80000 observations.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);library(zoo);setDT(df1)[abs(as.yearmon(Date)-as.yearmon(Expiry)) < 0.166]` after converting it to `Date` class

Comment: Also, `setDT(df1)[abs((year(Date)-year(Expiry))*12 + (month(Date)-month(Expiry)))<2]`

Comment: I think, it will filter data where Expiry lie within 2 months of Date(2/12=.166). Take this example : 2009-05-26    2009-07-24  36 . Above code would include this observation too, but i want exclude this. In this example, Expiry lie beyond next immediate month of Date, but within 2 month range.

Comment: My code was based on the example you provided.  It gives the expected result as showed.  Try the second one also.  BTW, I converted both the columns to `Date` class. i.e. `df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.POSIXlt, format= "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: `setDT(df1)[abs(as.yearmon(Date)-as.yearmon(Expiry)) < 0.166]
  #       Date     Expiry Close
#1: 2009-05-01 2009-06-26    12
#2: 2009-05-01 2009-05-26    22
#3: 2009-12-01 2009-12-26    33
#4: 2009-12-01 2010-01-24    36`

Comment: right now, i can not test these code, but I feel your second one would exclude second last observation provided in the original question. #: year(2009-12-01) {2009} -year(2010-01-24) {2010}. You multiplied their difference by 12. It will exceed 2 and would be excluded.

Comment: I get the same result as the expected one you showed.  Anyway, it looks like you want to take the days into consideration as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like this which is readable and fairly straightforward.

First, clean up the dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(Date= c('2009-05-01', '2009-05-01', '2009-05-01', '2009-05-01', '2009-12-01', '2009-12-01', '2009-12-01'),
                 Expiry=c('2009-06-26', '2009-05-26','2010-05-23', '2009-07-26', '2009-12-26', '2010-01-24', '2010-02-26'),
                 Close=c(12,22,36,32,33,36,32))

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
DF$Expiry <- as.Date(DF$Expiry)
```

In case you come across something like this:

```
2000-12-01       2010-02-26
```

the next line will remove these situations where years jump.

```
DF <- DF[which( (year(DF$Expiry) - year(DF$Date)>=0) & (year(DF$Expiry) - year(DF$Date)<2) ),]
```

First case: get all rows where the difference is one month in the same year.

```
DF1 <- DF[which( (month(DF$Expiry) - month(DF$Date)>=0) & (month(DF$Expiry) - month(DF$Date)<2) & (year(DF$Expiry) == year(DF$Date))),]
```

Next case: get all rows where the difference is one month, between Jan of Expiry and Dec of Date. This is since for months, 12 + 1 = 1.

```
DF2 <- DF[which( (month(DF$Expiry) ==1) & (month(DF$Date)==12) & (year(DF$Expiry) == (year(DF$Date)+1))),]

total <- rbind(DF1, DF2) 

total
```

should give you

```
        Date     Expiry Close
1 2009-05-01 2009-06-26    12
2 2009-05-01 2009-05-26    22
5 2009-12-01 2009-12-26    33
6 2009-12-01 2010-01-24    36
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Matt O´Brien. You saved my lots of work.You will be definitely acknowledge in my research work.

Comment: Great to hear it helped @Neeraj. If you think the answer is worthy, you could accept it.